# Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 migration redirect not working

Tags: 7, migrations

I am migrating a D6 site to D7 and for some odd reason the redirect module is not creating the redirections. Any ideas? I am not getting any errors, warnings or notices

This is what I have:

```
class MyNewsMigration extends MyNodeMigration {
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {

    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tag', '8')
         ->sourceMigration('Tag');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tag:source_type')->defaultValue('tid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tag:create_term')->defaultValue(FALSE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tag:ignore_case')->defaultValue(TRUE);

    // Redirect module to issue a 301 for each changing path
    $this->addFieldMapping('pathauto')->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('migrate_redirects', 'path');

  }
}
```

**Note:** I added the migrate.redirect.inc using patch from here https://www.drupal.org/node/1116408

Comment: Have you tried anything to debug this? Also, you reported a bad behaviour, but you didn't actually ask any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Migrate D2D with the redirect feature listed [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1116408) so that you only need to only have to do something like this:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('migrate_redirects', 'my_old_path');
```

**Do the following:**

> 1. In you class add something like this:

```
class MyNewsMigration extends MyNodeMigration {
  public function __construct(array $arguments) {

    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->addFieldMapping('migrate_redirects', 'my_old_path');

  }
}
```

> 2. Then what I was missing was the definition of the "my_old_path" in the prepareRow method.

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
  if (parent::prepareRow($row) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /* 
    You can query the DB to get the alias or 
    built it when you finish doing all the 
    processing assign it. 
  */

  $row->{'my_old_path'}  = 'PUT RESULT HERE';

}
```

> 3. Now you are ready to run your migration and rollbacks as need it.

**Note:** depending on your needs you can do at lot in the prepareRow to get the path of the old now or taxonomy term or any other entity.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different use case - changing aliases for users from /source/user-name to /author/user-name and creating redirects from the old alias the new one - but the steps are still the same.

First, I implemented a [complete()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1132582) method in my migrate class. This is called after the new entity (node, user, etc) has been created:

```
  /**
   * Implementation of MigrateDestinationEntity::complete() method.
   *
   * @param $entity
   * @param $row
   */
  function complete($account, $row) {
    // Create redirect from old Source alias that uses /source/
    // to new user profile alias.

    if (!redirect_load_by_source($row->dst)) {
      // First, get the alias for the user profile. We have to generate it separately
      // here because pathauto_create_alias() has already been run by the time the code
      // gets here, and we don't have access to that path.
      $new_alias = pathauto_create_alias('user', 'return', 'user/' . $account->uid, array('user' => $account));

      // Next, create the $redirect object and save it.
      $redirect = new stdClass();

      redirect_object_prepare(
        $redirect,
        array(
          'source' => $row->dst,
          'source_options' => array(),
          'redirect' => $new_alias,
          'redirect_options' => array(),
          'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
        )
      );
      redirect_save($redirect);
    }
  }
```

And then, to handle rollbacks (during development), I created a new class that overrides DrupalDestinationUser and implements a custom prepareRollback method:

```
class CNSUserDestination extends DrupalDestinationUser {
  // Add prepareRollback() method to this class.
  public function prepareRollback($uids) {
    parent::prepareRollback($uids);
    // Load all of the entities, since we need them for pathauto_create_alias().
    $users = entity_load('user', $uids);

    // Load pathauto.inc file.
    module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto');

    foreach ($users as $uid => $user) {
      $redirects[] = pathauto_create_alias('user', 'return', 'user/' . $user->uid, array('user' => $user));
    }

    // Delete redirects for user profiles.
    db_delete('redirect')
      ->condition('redirect', $redirects)
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sharing your code, it gave the inside I need it to make it work. I will be posting my answer below.